# Background subtraction in c#

Tags: background-subtraction

I'm studying a background subtraction technique.

I came to know that using the initialized library **Emgucv** can provide me with what I want. I want to get the output of a moving object. the object that moves should be in white colour and the rest of the things should be in black or any stationary colour.

I have downloaded some materials from internet for the reference purpose but all of them have been provided as .exe or .bat file. is there any way to convert or see the codes used to get that .bat or .exe files.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source code of a .bat file by opening it in a text editor such as Notepad.

It is possible to generate C# source code for a .NET executable by using a decompiler, such as [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/).

Note that the .exe might not be a .NET file, in which case it may be more difficult to recover the source code.